# Can a failed sideload take up storage?

Tags: internal-storage, side-loading, nexus

I have a stock Nexus 5, newest firmware, no root. Usually, I maintain 500 MB free space (have to clear cached data sometimes) to avoid error messages. Since yesterday, I have done these things:

1. Cleared data on the Hearthstone app
2. Updated Hearthstone, which is a big storage hog, but I don't think this update really cost me 500 MB
3. Sideloaded the most recent OTA update (full, not incremental OTA) using `adb sideload`.
4. Launches Hearthstone, which unpacks gigabytes of obb files.

Step 2 failed at first due to a bad USB connection. So I tried again, and it updated fine that time, going through "optimizing apps" and all that fun. However, after step 3, storage is full, all the way. Clearing cached data does nothing. Phone is slow to react, unstable, etc.

I have uninstalled Hearthstone now, freeing 3.33 GB, but I am sure reinstalling it will fill that space again, and again: I don't the previous version was much smaller.

So, my question is: Can the failed sideload be reason for this mess by taking up storage somewhere? Is there a way to clean this (without root)?

Comment: Failed installs are normally cleared/marked as crap then cleared by new data (that's how deleting works, kids!) So I doubt it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but maintaining only 500 MB free space will probably mean you can't download and instal many apps because they take up too much space. A single app can claim an instal size is needed but exceed it, I am pretty sure. This is partly because they download (or unzip) more resources when you try to use them.

Comment: @S.Mitchell: Correct. I sometimes need to clear cashed data before being able to update apps, even tiny ones. (For very big ones such as Hearthstone, I usually need to clear app data and/or uninstall, but that is not a Play Store restriction necessarily.)